# Is there any cli/cli addon that enables to easily filter it's output using a search string/regex?

Tags: bash, powershell, command-line-interface

(on windows)
I am running a non-stopping script (specifically, a "watch" script that watches changes in files and runs something, but it doesn't matter), and it emits 100s of lines. I am searching for a simple "gui-like" way to dynamically filter this output by some string or regex, so I can filter and see only a subset of the output. something like a filter box that you can change dynamically.

I prefer some PowerShell solution as this is how I run the script (need elevated mode and stuff), e.g., native PowerShell solution/add-on/extension/whatever. But I would love to also know about non-PowerShell solutions, like bash/cmd/whatever.

PS: Yes, I know I can write my own wrapping script that will run the inner script and filter the stdout, but I first want to know if there's some ready solution out there.

Thank you

Comment: Some terminal emulators support live filtering of the output. You would have to find one that works on Windows, though. Alternatively, you can pipe your program output through FZF (https://github.com/junegunn/fzf), which also supports live search.

Comment: Just to let you know, this question is not related to bash in linux.